# Slick MultiDB Configuration

Tags: scala, slick

Following this documentation:

http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/slick-multidb-3.0

It shows how one could write driver agnostic DAO layer using the cake pattern. It is actually for slick version 3.0, but when I looked at the GitHub repo, it uses slick 2.x.x version. I'm now finding it hard to use that idea as in slick 3.0 there is no more slick.driver.simple that I could import!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid looking at the master branch. There is a separate branch that uses Slick 3.0.0 version!